# Verdaccio is complaining that "package XXX does not have a latest tag?"

Tags: json, npm, verdaccio

On startup of Verdaccio, all the packages throw warnings like the one below

 `warn --- package zone.js does not have a "latest" tag?`

When startup is complete, the UI says that no packages were loaded.

It seems to be related to a publish, but I can't seem to get a solution.

We currently have 1005 packages in the sinopia-db file, so I am hoping for a solution that does not involve manually publishing every package.

[Edit]
Verdaccio version: 3.8.5
Windows Server 2008

Comment: Why all the packages do not have the `latest` tag?

Comment: @JuanPicado, I have no idea. The files all have "dist-tag":"[]"

Comment: Ok, using the latest version of verdaccio if you publish a new version and latest is missing or dist-tags is empty, it assign the published version as latest.

Comment: Also you did not described which version of Verdaccio, so, hard to match wether was an issue fixed in the past.

Comment: I added the version info.

Comment: Does that solve your issue?

Comment: @JuanPicado I updated to 3.10.1 and I still get the error.

Comment: I would upload a small example storage to GitHub otherwise hard to reproduce. It might be a bug or just a bad practice that someone removes the tags in purpose